# setting LINK variable in Makefile generated by qmake (5.0)

Tags: linux, gcc, qmake

I'm using qmake to generate a Makefile. In my spec file, I override CXX and CC as such:

```
QMAKE_CC=/home/foo/gcc-4.7.2/bin/gcc
QMAKE_CXX=/home/foo/gcc-4.7.2/bin/g++
```

Now the generated Makefile uses those versions. However there is a variable called LINK in the generated makefile, which points to g++. Not `/home/foo/gcc-4.7.2/bin/g++`.

This causes my build to fail at the final step when compiling the executable from all the generated object files.

How do I get qmake to set LINK to `/home/foo/gcc-4.7.2/bin/g++` in the generated Makefile?

Currently, I'm changing LINK by hand to get things to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can override LINK in the same way:

QMAKE_LINK=/home/foo/gcc-4.7.2/bin/g++

Comment: You can also use QMAKE_LINK=$${QMAKE_CXX}